# How to get latitude and longitude coordinates of a svg map's starting point(x=0,y=0)?

Tags: javascript, svg, latitude-longitude

I am using an svg map downloaded from [wikimedia](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/61/Alaska_boroughs_and_census_areas.svg). I need to get the svg's starting point's latitude and longitude coordinates so based on that I want to plot some points on the svg map.

Else is there any way to plot cities on svg map using its actual latitude and longitude coordinates?

Can any one help me to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You should use [polymaps](http://polymaps.org) for svg maps together with [cloudmade](http://cloudmade.com)

Comment: Is it possible to use wikimedia maps instead of using polymaps?

Comment: Mmm... and this http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/data-visualisation/introduction-svg-scripting-interactive-map ?